# Discount Coupon Code disappearing at checkout

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, coupon, coupon-codes, onestepcheckout

I am having an issue where the coupon code inputted by a customer later disappears when checking out. Basically the customer inputs the coupon code and it looks fine but when they go checkout and type in their info, the coupon disappears. Can anyone help?

Comment: did you set any restrictions for payment methods or anything like only for guests , please check configuration once......

Comment: No, the coupon is working when it is inputted but as you continue checkout and reach the order review page the coupon is gone.

Comment: did you switch to other themes like `default` & try once.....

Comment: No I have not. Can't really do that at the moment since it would change my live sites theme.

Comment: well, if you have any demo site or staging or localhost, you may need to try , i am not sure, theme is issue, but you can try once when you get chance......

Comment: Thanks, odd thing is that it is happening on 2 of my magento sites.

Comment: did you found solution ?

Comment: No I've been having to add specials without coupon codes instead.